# Build failed for TFS 2013 from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to create a build from VS 2010 for TFS 2013. I am getting the following error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the `<Import>` declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Do I have to install VS 2010 on the TFS server?

Comment: Is this the first build you've created? Do any other builds work?

Comment: Yes, I created this build. This is the first build I am trying with TFS 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should install VS 2010 on the build server.  It can live side-by-side with other versions (so you could have VS 2010 + VS 2012 + VS 2013 all installed on your build server if you wished).